# Can't block site in /etc/hosts

Tags: hosts-file

In my /etc/hosts I have added this line to block the [www.bbc.com/persian](http://www.bbc.com/persian):

```
127.0.0.1 www.bbc.com/persian
```

I am using Firefox on Antix Linux (Debian), and had no success, the site can still be reached just as before. How can I block that page by using /etc/hosts?

Comment: remove `/persian`.  If you don't want to block bbc altogether, then you can't do so with hosts.  The hosts file just prevents dns from looking up the root website.. in this case, `www.bbc.com`

Comment: You might also want to block simply have `bbc.com` in the `hosts` file as many sites can and do drop the `www` and will work if you block `www.bbc.com`.